# Problem opening SFX archive file(.exe) using the archive manager

Tags: file-format, 8.04

I have installed both rar and unrar using apt-install but I am still not able to use archive manager for opening the archive file.. I have also tried installing p7zip(p7zip-full and p7zip) but no improvements...

However, when I use command-line for extracting the files from the archive using unrar or rar the command executes successfully...

Is there any other open source software I should install for viewing the contents of the SFX archive or what else should I install to view the same in the archive manager..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com/

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities that I can think of, the obvious one being [wine](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wine) which should be able to deal with it as all that is needed to extract it is internal to the `.exe` itself. However both `7z` and `rar` are able to create `sfx` archives and nowhere does it say they can open them. Another possibility is it's password protected.

To install wine in Ubuntu hardy 8.04 I would recommend installing from their ppa at launchpad to do this open software sources from the administration menu[image: software sources add source] and add these two lines

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu hardy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu hardy main
```

then open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update` then once this has completed `sudo apt-get install wine`

Comment: The file is not password protected as I am able to open it through command line without using any password...

Comment: Can you please provide the link of wine for Ubuntu 8.04(64-bit) as I am not able to find one...

Comment: you should be able to install wine from the ubuntu repositories just type sudo apt-get install wine in terminal or you can get a more up to date package from wine's ppa at Launchpad I have added install instructions to the bottom of my answer

Comment: A 7zip SFX are three files concatenated: the exe for extracting, an (optional?) configuration file and finally the archive. It should be possible to extract it without using wine.